# Truncate decimal places

Tags: c#, floating-point

In one finance application I'm working on, the requirements call that I truncate a decimal value at certain number of places and not round.

Example: 11.685 truncated to 2 decimal places should be 11.68

I wrote this extension method, but was wondering if someone knew of an easier way.

```
public static class DecimalExtentsions
{
    public static decimal TruncateDecimalPlaces(this decimal val, int places)
    {
        if (places <= 0)
            return Math.Truncate(val);

        var dv = Math.Pow(10, places);
        decimal part = (val % 1) * Convert.ToDecimal(dv);
        val -= (part % 1) / Convert.ToDecimal(dv);
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Following [Hans' advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding): `Math.Truncate(100 * value) / 100;` where `100` can be substituted by `1 * 10^places`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can use Math.Round() to truncate a number by removing 0.5 / 10 ^ places and then rounding

**e.g** 
     11.685 to 2 places

```
Math.Round(11.685 - 0.005, 2)
```

The following seems to do the job

```
public static class NumberExtensions {
    public static decimal TruncateDecimalPlaces(this decimal val, int places) {
        if (places < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("places");
        }
        return Math.Round(val - Convert.ToDecimal((0.5 / Math.Pow(10, places))), places);
    }
}



[TestMethod]
public void TruncateToPlaces() {

    Assert.AreEqual(10.665m, 10.6651M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 3));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.665m, 10.6653M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 3));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.665m, 10.6655M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 3));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.665m, 10.6657M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 3));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.665m, 10.665789M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 3));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.665m, 10.66599999M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 3));

    Assert.AreEqual(10m, 10.66599999M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 0));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.6m, 10.66599999M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 1));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.66m, 10.66599999M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 2));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.665m, 10.66599999M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 3));
    Assert.AreEqual(10.6659m, 10.66599999M.TruncateDecimalPlaces( 4));

}
```

Comment: This will fail on negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

What does `dv` mean? Use descriptive variable names. `Val` and `Places` Make sense. `part` is *okay*, but would be better as `dec_part` or `decimal_part`. We're no longer restricted on the bytes we use for variables. You shouldn't act like we are.

Answer (score 0):

My solution multiplies the value by 10<sup>places</sup>, truncates, and finally divides by the same power of ten. If the places are negative, the decimals before the decimal point are truncated; i.e., `1234.TruncateDecimalPlaces(-2) ==> 1200`.

Since `Math.Pow` is works on doubles, I'm using my own implementation of the power function. However; if the precision of the `Math.Pow` gives you good enough results, just use that one.

```
public static decimal TruncateDecimalPlaces(this decimal val, int places)
{
    var dv = DecimalPow(10m, places);
    return Math.Truncate(dv * val) / dv;
}

private static decimal DecimalPow(decimal b, int exp)
{
    decimal result = 1m;
    if (exp >= 0) {
        while (exp > 0) {
            if (exp % 2 != 0) {
                result *= b;
            }
            exp /= 2;
            b *= b;
        }
    } else {
        do {
            if (exp % 2 != 0) {
                result /= b;
            }
            exp /= 2;
            b *= b;
        } while (exp < 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```